# How to organize request from ROOM DB which Flowable<List> and could work with toList()?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

```
 fun loadItems(id: Int): Flowable<List<Item>> {
return dao.loadItems(id).toFlowable()}
```

it works because `dao.loadItems()` returns `Single`, but 
I want to have Flowable (to listen DB changes) and have toList()
my old code where `dao.loadItems()` returns Single

```
 val items = shoppingListsRepository.loadItems(shoppingListId)
    .flatMapIterable { shoppingListItem -> shoppingListItem }
    .flatMap { shoppingListItem ->
      loadOfferForShoppingListItem(shoppingListItem.offerId)
          .map { offer ->
            Pair(shoppingListItem, offer)
          }
          .map { it -> shoppingListWithOffer(it.first, it.second) }
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    }.toList()
    .toFlowable()
```

here is my new code ,it works but when I change the return type to Flowable for loadItems() it doesn't work? Am I doing something wrong?

```
  val items = shoppingListsRepository.loadShoppingListItems(shoppingListId)
    .flatMap { it ->Flowable.fromIterable(it)}
    .flatMap { shoppingListItem ->
      loadOfferForShoppingListItem(shoppingListItem.offerId)
          .map { offer -> Pair(shoppingListItem, offer) }
          .map { it -> shoppingListWithOffer(it.first, it.second) }
    }.toList()
    .toFlowable()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your stream inside flatMap. This way you'll get updates:

```
repository.loadItems(id)
   .flatMap { 
       Flowable.fromIterrable(it)
       ... (do your thing here)
       .toList()
}
```

Comment: @mismzniac  Could you please have a look on my code?

Comment: Wait.. why do you just change what output of room in: loadShoppingListItems to flowable? It should emit list on every table change.
Try without flatMapIterable, just to make sure Room emits properly, then add flatMap the way I've mentioned previously. 
You can't use toList() inside infinite emissions from flowable.